# When I press register button my app has crashed but data insert successfully in database

Tags: ios, nsstring, uibutton, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

Here is my response code.

```
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSDictionary *LoginResult = (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];

NSLog(@"Success");

NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray = [LoginResult objectForKey:@"Response"];

for(NSDictionary *countname in wholeJsonArray)
{

    NSString *countryName = [countname objectForKey:@"country_name"];
    if(countryName)
        [countryArray addObject:countryName];
    NSString *stateName=[countname objectForKey:@"state_name"];
    if(stateName)
        [stateArray addObject:stateName];
}
```

above code is retrieve to country name and statename .

When i debug my code after press button apps should crashed  in `NSString *countryName = [countname objectForKey:@"country_name"];` line cursor point.

Comment: is there any crash logs ?

Comment: Button press code is sending requesting

Comment: crash log [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a6e570

Comment: This line  NSString *countryName = [countname objectForKey:@"country_name"]; only run from country name and statename selection. But last time(button press) then also this line run on debugging process and crashed.

Comment: just check the countname class by NSLog(@"%@",[countName class]) I think this should be of type nsstring.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableArray *wholeJsonArray` does not contain `NSMutableDictionary` ; It contains `NSString` instead. Please review your array contents.

Comment: Its not any problem because my apps works fine before pressing register button

Comment: @MalayPatel:No there is the problem. Have checked the data where you are saving whether it is right ?